# How to set X-frame-options header in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have application with struts 2

For upload file i am using iframe as target for form submission.

It gave me error -

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://localhost:8081/finance/uploadFile does not permit framing.
```

I checked X-Frame-Options in the request and it was **DENY**

In order to permit X-Frame-Options, I added an interceptor like this -

```
@Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext ac = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ac.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
    response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
    return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
```

But still i see value of X-Frame-Options **ALLOWALL,DENY**

And browser gives me this error -

**Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('ALLOWALL, DENY') encountered when loading 'http://localhost:8081/finance/uploadFile'. Falling back to 'DENY'.**

I don't understand i am setting request header ALLOWALL only but from where does it get DENY.

Can somebody please help how to do it correctly.

Comment: Could you add the complete header in that interceptor with `getHeaders`? Also I don't think `ALLOWALL` is a valid option, have you read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: Are you using other frameworks too, like spring security?

Comment: Thank you @AlirezaFattahi yes i am using spring security here and that's were the ghost was. Got it solved.

Comment: Yes @beendr you are right ALLOWALL is not a valid option. I used SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from Alireza Fattahi's comment.

I am also using spring security along with struts. And it was spring security that was adding X-Frame-Options - DENY by default.

I made following change in my spring security configuration to change default behaviour.

```
<sec:headers>
    <sec:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
</sec:headers>
```

in `<sec:http>` tag